# Jquery how to checked the checkbox in between

Tags: jquery

[image]

how do I tick the Code 6000, and it will auto checked the checkbox in between 7000? this also goes to between 7000 and 7004 if 7000 is checked

```
    $('.mGrid tr').each(function () {
    if (!this.rowIndex) return;
    if ($(this).find("td:eq(2)").text() =='S') {
        $(this).css({
            'font-weight': '800',
            'background-color': '#DBFF94',
            'border' : '2px solid black'
        });

    }
});
<table class="mGrid" cellspacing="0" rules="rows" border="1" id="GridView1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr align="left">
                <th scope="col">
                                <span class="chkHeader"><input id="GridView1_chkAll" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$nnn$GridView1$ctl01$chkAll" /></span>
                            </th><th scope="col">Code</th><th scope="col">Sub Code</th><th scope="col">Title</th><th scope="col">Description</th><th class="HiddenColumn" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>
                                <span class="chkItem"><input id="GridView1_chkCheck_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$nnn$GridView1$ctl02$chkCheck" /></span>
                            </td><td>1000</td><td>S</td><td>Main</td><td>Summary of everything </td><td class="HiddenColumn"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$nnn$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Select$0&#39;)">Select</a></td>
            </tr><tr class="alt">
                <td>
                                <span class="chkItem"><input id="GridView1_chkCheck_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$nnn$GridView1$ctl03$chkCheck" /></span>
                            </td><td>6000</td><td>S</td><td>Report</td><td>All Reports</td><td class="HiddenColumn"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$nnn$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Select$1&#39;)">Select</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Added the html part, kinda messy a bit

####Updated

If I want to select either 1 in between, example, checked either 6001-6005, code 6000 checkbox will auto checked, how can I do that?
$(this).closest('tr').prevUntil('tr.lights').css('background-color','black'); I try prevUntil, but it highlight nearly all prev
$(this).closest('tr').prev('tr.lights').css('background-color','black'); this only able to highlight if it near to the green row

Comment: You need to show how the HTML is structured as well.

Comment: ... otherwise we won't be able to properly help you. Anyways, the solution likely involves http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/.

Comment: looking at nextUntil now, hmm, it look like what im looking for, but need to study a bit with this

Answer (score 0):

If your content is created dynamicaly you could add a custom attribute to the grouped elements like `data-group="6000"` so you ca do something like:

```
$('[data-group]').click(function(){
$("[data-group='"+this.attr('data-group')+"']").attr('checked','checked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the working version http://jsbin.com/edamuh/3/edit

If you had the following HTML (note that the inputs are siblings)

```
  1<input type="checkbox"/>
  2<input type="checkbox"/>
  3<input type="checkbox"/>
  4<input type="checkbox"/>
  5<input type="checkbox"/>
  6<input type="checkbox"/>
  7<input type="checkbox"/>
  8<input type="checkbox"/>
  9<input type="checkbox"/>
  0<input type="checkbox"/>
```

You could use the following snippet to check checkboxes until the next checked one

```
 $('input').click(function(){
    var $t = $(this);
    var unchkds = $t.nextUntil('input:checked', 'input[type="checkbox"]');
    var allInputsAfterN = $t.nextAll('input').length;
    if(unchkds.length > 0 && unchkds.length != allInputsAfterN) {
       console.log(unchkds.length + " unchecked after. " + allInputsAfterN + " total after");
      unchkds.prop('checked', true);
    }
  });
```

You'd have to do something similar for checking checkboxes backwards (using prevUntil & prevAll)

Comment: awww, feel so cozy, need to study the use of this prevUntil & prevAll